# How to replace values in a column of a dataframe with the values of another column based on matches to a third column?

Tags: r

I have a problem when trying to convert the values of a dataframe with four variables into the values of a specific column in another dataframe with two variables based on matches between a third column.

In a dataframe df1 I have a meta_# which corresponds to an iso_# represented in the same row as the meta_#. I want the corresponding iso_# to replace the meta_# in df2 when the meta_# in the dataframes matches.

With a simplified dataset e.g.:

When df1$V1 matches with the value of any of the values in df2$V1, df2$V2, df2$V3 and df2$V4 I want the values in df2 to be replaced with the value of df1$V2 in the same row as the respective match

df1

```
     V1      V2
1 meta_123 iso_321
2 meta_234 iso_987
3 meta_345 iso_876
4 meta_456 iso_765
5 meta_567 iso_543
6 meta_789 iso_423
```

df2

```
     V1        V2       V3      V4
1 meta_123 meta_234 meta_345 meta_456
2 meta_123 meta_234 meta_345 meta_567
3 meta_123 meta_345 meta_567 meta_789
4 meta_234 meta_567 meta_456 meta_789
etc...
```

I then want the following
df3

```
     V1      V2      V3     V4
1 iso_321 iso_987 iso_876 iso_765
2 iso_321 iso_987 iso_876 iso_543
3 iso_321 iso_876 iso_543 iso_423
4 iso_987 iso_543 iso_765 iso_423
etc...
```

I tried with

```
df3 <- as.data.frame(ifelse(df2 %in% df1$V1, df1$V2))
```

But it just returns the list of df1$V2 in the same order as it is.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `match` :

```
df2[] <- df1$V2[match(as.matrix(df2), df1$V1)]
df2

#       V1      V2      V3      V4
#1 iso_321 iso_987 iso_876 iso_765
#2 iso_321 iso_987 iso_876 iso_543
#3 iso_321 iso_876 iso_543 iso_423
#4 iso_987 iso_543 iso_765 iso_423
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df2 %>%
     mutate(across(everything(), ~ deframe(df1)[.]))
#       V1      V2      V3      V4
#1 iso_321 iso_987 iso_876 iso_765
#2 iso_321 iso_987 iso_876 iso_543
#3 iso_321 iso_876 iso_543 iso_423
#4 iso_987 iso_543 iso_765 iso_423
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df2[] <- setNames(df1$V2, df1$V1)[as.matrix(df2)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("meta_123", "meta_234", "meta_345", "meta_456", 
"meta_567", "meta_789"), V2 = c("iso_321", "iso_987", "iso_876", 
"iso_765", "iso_543", "iso_423")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

df2 <- structure(list(V1 = c("meta_123", "meta_123", "meta_123", "meta_234"
), V2 = c("meta_234", "meta_234", "meta_345", "meta_567"), V3 = c("meta_345", 
"meta_345", "meta_567", "meta_456"), V4 = c("meta_456", "meta_567", 
"meta_789", "meta_789")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```